# Problem with \ifthenelse

Tags: ifthenelse

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{theyear}
\setcounter{theyear}{\number\year}
\newcommand{\shorttoday}
{
\ifthenelse{\number\month<5}{May, }{\ifthenelse{\number\month <8}{August, }
{\addtocounter{theyear}{1} January, }}\value{theyear}}
\begin{document}

%\number\month
\shorttoday

\end{document}
```

Why this result?

```
Missing number, treated as zero
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.14
```

Comment: `\value{theyear}` doesn't print the value; for that you should use `\thetheyear`. All `\number` tokens you're using are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with `\ifthenelse`. You have a misplaced `\value{theyear}`, which should be `\thetheyear`, for printing the value.

Why does a “Missing number” error shows up? You have to know that `\value{theyear}` just produces the symbolic name of the counter, not its value; when TeX finds a counter name and it is not looking for a number, it starts an assignment, but it finds no number to assign to the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{theyear}
\setcounter{theyear}{\year}
\newcommand{\shorttoday}{%
  \ifthenelse{\month<5}%
    {May, }%
    {\ifthenelse{\month <8}%
      {August, }%
      {\addtocounter{theyear}{1}January, }%
    }%
  \thetheyear
}
\begin{document}

\shorttoday

\end{document}
```

I reformatted the code, removing all spurious spaces you had and also the redundant `\number` tokens.

Comment: I will have to say thanks for helping me a lot.